# EJS loop on null collection still evaluates?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am attempting what should be a simple operation in EJS, executing a for loop on a collection if the collection exists.

```
<% if(typeof applicant.customerContacts != 'undefined' 
     && applicant.customerContacts) { %>
       <% applicant.customerContacts.forEach(function(contact) { %>
           <div>
               //stuff goes here
           </div>
       <% } %>    
<% } %>
```

However I keep getting this error at runtime:

> [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in {redacted}/applicantOverview.ejs while compiling ejs]

How can I write the loop to handle if the data might be null/missing from the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

I was missing a closing paren on the foreach call.

Moving on....